# Hadoop Pseudo-Distributed : SSH command

Tags: java, hadoop, ssh, jar

I have a single machine, in my university, with hadoop configured in pseudo-distributed mode and I need to control it from home.

If i connect from SSH I have some problem:

If i launch this command:

```
./hadoop jar 'my.jar' hdfs://localhost:54310
```

then the jar must be on computer with Hadoop. Is there is a solution to run a jar that is on my home computer?

Similarly, how I can use get/put command to get/put from/to my home computer and the HDFS filesystem?

For now I have a dropbox folder where I "put and move" the file, but isn't a very clean solution.

Another big problem is that if I run a jar through SSH and then I close the SSH connection, the work stop. But I need to start a work on Hadoop and power off my home computer. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my answers to your questions:

1. The jar file must be on the system with Hadoop installed in order to run it.
2. If you're running a windows environment on your home computer, you can use WinSCP to get/put files from your home computer to the Hadoop system. Then you'll have to issue a `hadoop fs -put or hadoop fs -get` command to put/get files from HDFS to the local FS on the hadoop system. I'm not aware of an easy way to get/put files from your home computer to HDFS. 
   If you're running a unix environment, you can just issue an SCP command from your terminal/console.
3. Yes, if you SSH into a machine, issue a command & then close the SSH connection, the execution stops. You can however, run the command as a background process, and the execution will continue even after you close the SSH connection. You need to append an ampersand: `&` to the end of your command. Example:

   ```
   ./hadoop jar 'my.jar' hdfs://localhost:54310 &
   ```

**EDIT**

Command to redirect output to file:

```
./hadoop jar 'my.jar' hdfs://localhost:54310 > outputFile &
```

Comment: 3. If i use the & I can make another login after some hours to check the state of the process? how? 2. At home I've Mac OS, at university ubuntu. The scp command [is this?](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

Comment: If you're running a jar file like I mentioned in the example, there are 2 ways you can check the progress. 1. Go to Job Tracker URL, find your job, and track the progress there. 2. You can redirect the output of the job to a file. So when you login later, you can just read the file and see the progress. please check my edit for the command to write output of the command to file

Comment: And if I open the file while the process is running (with redirect) there is no problem?